# Is it ok to repeat the same text in alt & title attributes for non-link <img> tags (e.g. for screen reader users)?

Tags: xhtml, usability, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers

```
<img src="young-girl-in-red-gown.jpg" 
     alt="young girl in red gown" 
     title="Young girl in red gown"/>
```

Is my above example a good example? Should it be always like this?

In above example I used a file name, alt text and title text that are almost the same.

- Is it ok to use same text for `alt` and `title` even if it's not a link, or can this repetition can create problems for screen reader? (I'm repeating the text because FireFox doesn't show alt as a tooltip, and the client wants a tooltip.)
- Should we use `title` with image if the image is not in a link?
- Should `alt` and `title` be different always?
- Do screen readers speak all these attributes for images?

  1. Image file name
  2. `alt` text
  3. `title` text
- Should I always use a descriptive image file name?

Comment: Readers should note that this question changed *drastically*, so some of the below answers won't quite match up. See the revision here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2286183/revisions

Comment: question is not changed it's expanded

Answer (score 2):

I use the Jaws screen reader and having both alt and title set isn't an issue. Jaws reads the alt tag by default if present and ignores the title unless specifically told to read it. I can't say what other screen readers do though.

Answer (score 1):

See:

**[The Importance of Images On Your Site](http://rawnuke.com/the-importance-of-images-on-your-site/)**

**[ALT vs. TITLE](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/alt-vs-title-attributes-images-html/)**

The `alt` and `title` attribute are there for different things, they are not the same, they won't irritate anything, they are made to make things much more clear to both *humans as well as search engines*.

Using `alt` tag is good for standard-compliant, validated html and it is also equally respected by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

No idea about screen reader users, but it bugs the heck out of me.

I doubt search engines care.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that this should cause a problem unless you are stuffing keywords into that to increase keyword density on the pages. otherwise it is alright to have it the way your client wants.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that `alt` was how you created mouseover tooltips over images. Luckily, with the advent of `title`, this is not really needed.

If you wish to provide such a tooltip today, over either a text link or an image, `title` is the thing to use.

`alt` is what you use to make your images "visible" as text to browser technology that doesn't actually support images (such as screen readers, or text-based browsers). Thus, it doesn't have any meaning in the context of text links - since text in those is already, well, text.

Search engines' algorithms are a bit of mystery. If I had to guess, I would say that for web searches, there is so much signals available through text links, that there is no need to rely on `title`s and `alt`s. Image search may be a different story. It's much harder to get information about what's contained in a picture and correlate it to textual keywords. Therefore, these attributes may be given more weight in that context.

Comment: The alt tag is required for Section 508 compliance and is used by Assisted Technologies like JAWS. The title tag is optional and provides hover text (mouse over) for some browsers.